# Chromecast - Check before connect or launch

Tags: javascript, objective-c, chromecast

I'm using [CastVideos-ios](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios) example hosted on GitHub by Kevin Nilson.

First of all I am so sorry if this is something than sound a little strange or that is not necessary to do, but I have this problem to solve.

What i'm trying to do is deny access/connect if some user is already seeing/casting media on TV.

For now is this, **my future goal is create a queue for manage a number of users**, let me explain:

In a home, with one TV and one Chromecast on it, the family/users share the same network and want to cast on the same TV, how I manage this without disconnect the active user?

From the device(iPhone), could at least give a warning saying "You are about to disconnect iPhone of Someone" - Yes or Not.

Don't know if I have to implement this in the sender like I'm shown below or in a receiver with JavaScript.

Thank you for your time.

(Update)

```
- (void)connectToDevice:(GCKDevice *)device {

    NSLog(@"Device address: %@:%d", device.ipAddress, (unsigned int) device.servicePort);
    self.selectedDevice = device;

    NSDictionary *info = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString *appIdentifier = [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    self.deviceManager =
    [[GCKDeviceManager alloc] initWithDevice:self.selectedDevice clientPackageName:appIdentifier];
    self.deviceManager.delegate = self;


    // check if someone is already connected or playing media ...
    // the problem here is than I only can disconnect my own device

    if (_streamDuration > 0) { // if the current stream duration is greater than 0 ...

        // than disconnect
        [self.deviceManager leaveApplication];
        [self.deviceManager disconnect];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"You are about to disconnect iPhone of Someone" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Not" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alert show];

        //reset the button status ...

    // connect    
    } else {

        [self.deviceManager connect];

    }


    // Start animating the cast connect images.
    UIButton *chromecastButton = (UIButton *)self.chromecastBarButton.customView;
    chromecastButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    chromecastButton.imageView.animationImages =
    @[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_cast_on0.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_cast_on1.png"],
       [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_cast_on2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_cast_on1.png"] ];
    chromecastButton.imageView.animationDuration = 2;
    [chromecastButton.imageView startAnimating];


}
```

Comment: You should comply with the Cast Design Checklist and not change the behavior of the Cast button.

Comment: Thanks @LeonNicholls but there in the Cast Design Checklist say "when cast receivers are available", technically is available but if someone press the button to connect and there are someone already seeing media, they are disconnected without any warning, this is the problem than I need to solve.

Comment: That is how the product currently works.

Comment: Thank you, the product is great, I love it, but I just think it would be a good feature on it, do you? I really like to go forward with that, can you give me some light how to do that?